# angular 4 preventing from showing components on partial paths

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6

In my app I have routing set up the following way:

1. the **app-routing.module**

   ```
   {path: 'login', loadChildren:'./components/login/login.module#LoginModule'}
   ```
2. the **login-routing.module**

   ```
   {
     path:'main', <--- contains router outlet, shows frame design, login/main
     component: LoginLoaderComponent,
     children: [
         { path: 'withsms', component: LoginWithSmsComponent } <--- login/main/withsms one of the login pages
     ]
   {
   ```
3. **login/main** - is the frame from all nested login components (different login pages) and holds a **router-outlet** common design for all of them.
4. When user navigates to **login/main - he sees only the partial component**

Question is how do I prevent this from happening, and navigating user to a default page?

Comment: i think if you share code on stackbiz then it helpful

Comment: Its prety straight forward... /path1/path2/.
path1 = frame design component with router outlet.
path2 = component loaded in to path1's routeroutlet.
on navigate to /path1 dont show frame design, but nevigate to some default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally the way I solved this is using **canActivate**, which I already used in the past for server side authentication, for permissions to navigate to a page.
In this case I just analyzed the route to see if its length follows the route convention

of:
**/container-component/nested-component**

and that the paths to only the **/container-component** component wont show the empty container. I did this by checking the length of the path to verify it exceeds the length of 1, in which case it would ether resolve to a found url by return an **Observable.of(true)**, or it would re-navigate and return **Observable.of(false)**

the solution looks like this:

**login-routing.module**

```
@Injectable()
export class LoginAuthGuard implements CanActivate {
constructor(private _router: Router) {}
// check here if navigated route confirms to convention
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    let urlArr = state['url'].split('/');
    urlArr = urlArr.splice(2,urlArr.length-1);
    if(urlArr.length > 1) {
        // if it does let it be resolved
        return Observable.of(true);
    }else {
        // if it doesn't navigate to a default page and return a false observable
        this._router.navigate(['login/main/withsms']);
        return Observable.of(false);
    }
}
}
const routes: Routes = [
{
  path:'main',
  component: LoginLoaderComponent,
  children: [
      { path: 'withsms', component: LoginWithSmsComponent }...
  ]
}
];
```

**app-routing.module**

```
const routes: Routes = [
{ path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: '/main/withpassword'},
{ path: 'login', loadChildren:'./components/login/login.module#LoginModule',
     canActivate:[LoginAuthGuard] <--- all routes to login/... will be checked by LoginAuthGuard
},
{ path: 'upload',loadChildren: './components/upload-page/upload-page.module#UploadPageModule'},
{ path: '**', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'login'}
];
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because you don't have any default component to show at `/login/main`.
I suggest you rewrite the `login-routing.module.ts` like this.

```
[
  { path: '', component: LoginSelectionComponent }, <--- Login Selection , URL will be /login/ itself
  { path: 'withsms', component: LoginWithSmsComponent } <--- login/withsms one of the login pages
]
```

And you can put other login methods too...

Comment: The problem will continue to exists, only with one less path name.If I'll navigate to login/ the frame will still show empty with no components loaded into it, only now under /login and not under login/main

Comment: you need to create `LoginSelectionComponent` for the empty path.

Comment: I'm trying to solve this using the **canActivate** attribute of **Routes**, I'm already using this for server authentication, but I figured it can also be used for this scenario. If there's a better way I would love to hear it.